# Splitting very large csv files into smaller files

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed

Is Dask proper to read large csv files in parallel and split them into multiple smaller files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, dask can read large CSV files.  It will split them into chunks

```
df = dd.read_csv("/path/to/myfile.csv")
```

Then, when saving, Dask always saves CSV data to multiple files

```
df.to_csv("/output/path/*.csv")
```

See the read_csv and to_csv docstrings for much more information about this.

- [dd.read_csv](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv)
- [dd.DataFrame.to_csv](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to produce a basic dataframe but the logic shouldn't be too different in your case as you just need to consider location.

## Generate dataframe

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

N = int(1e6)
df = pd.DataFrame({"member":np.random.choice(letters, N),
                   "values":np.random.rand(N)})

df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

## One `parquet` file (folder) per member

If you're happy to have the output in as `parquet` you can just use the option `partition_on` as

```py
df = dd.read_csv("file.csv")
df.to_parquet("output", partition_on="member")
```

If you then really need `csv` you can convert to this format. I strongly suggest you to move your data to `parquet`.