# Split a very large csv file into many smaller files

Tags: python-3.x

I read this question but it does not seem to give a good reply to my situation (maybe I misread it):
[Splitting very large csv files into smaller files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068714/splitting-very-large-csv-files-into-smaller-files)

I have a large CSV file (1.0 Gb) with lots of individual rows (over 1 million) and 8 columns.  Two columns represent date and time while others represent other stock related information (price, etc.).  I would like to save individual files separated by date and time attributes.  So, if there are 100 different combinations of date-time, I would extract rows for each combination and save is as a separate CSV file under subfolder like C:/Date/Time/filename.csv.

I am currently using pandas to filter each time-date combination to get a dataset with required information for that combination and then saving each file using loops (a list of date-time combinations is looped through).  This is taking a very long time.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

(I will look into multithreading as well but I don't believe it will solve the speed issue significantly).

Thanks!

Adding a sample of input data:

[image]

Comment: What does *"combinations of date-time"* mean, exactly? Show a meaningful sample of the input. Also explain if the input is ordered by date.

Comment: @Tomalak, I added a sample of input data.  Column quote_datetime has a date and time (hours:minutes).  There is also a date column called expiration; there may be a lot of different expiration dates even though only one is shown in the sample I added.  I need to save different files with all columns listed in the sample where each hour/minutes from quote_datetime column and each expiration date form a unique combination: a file for 9:31 and 9/7/2016, another file for 9:32 and 9/7/2016, etc.

Comment: "Is there a better way to accomplish this?" - Yes, it's called SQL.

Comment: @Antimon, can you please elaborate on this?  I am new to working with such large quantities of data.  Are you suggesting putting everything in a database instead of csv files? Or putting in a database and then creating csv files using the database?

Comment: I'd suggest putting your 1 GB csv file into a SQL database. That will definitely be a better tool than wrangling everything from single csv file with python. If you must, you can still export subsets of that data to csv files later on.

Comment: That's solid advice. Read all of it into an 8-column table, set up indexes on the date columns, and use SQL to query the data set. A million rows is nothing for a half-way decent database.